# renaming a folder or copying it to local machine (and all contents) using gsutil-- Folder name has an asterisk (*) in the google bucket

Tags: bucket, gsutil

I am new in using gsutil. I was trying to copy a folder from Google Buckets to my local machine.

```
gsutil cp -r gs://myBucket/MyBucketFolder/*
```

Using this command I am able to copy most of the folders and contents except for those whose folder name has an asterisk (*). One of the folders inside "gs://myBucket/MyBucketFolder/" is named "DC*Program"

Is there a work around that you can recommend?

I also tried the

```
gsutil mv gs://myBucket/MyBucketFolder/DC*Program gs://myBucket/MyBucketFolder/DCProgram
```

to try and rename the folder but the issue is still the same.

On both commands, I get this message. "contains a wildcard; gsutil does not currently support objects with wildcards in their name."

Thanks

I was copying a folder from Google buckets to my local machine folder